# Calculating full width half max in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, automation

I am trying to automate full-width half max in python. I have a data frame with 6 lines (signals). I can do it for one signal at a time but I want to make it for all signals in the data frame. Here is how my code looks like so far:

First I import and plot the data frame just to get an idea of how everything looks, as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("Values_S250_3_level_YS.csv")
plt.plot(df)
```

Then I make a list to print all the values from the data frame into it as follows:

```
listb = []      # to print all the values of dataframe in a list form
for name, values in df.iteritems():
    print('{name}: {value}'.format(name=name, value=values))
    listb.append(values)
```

So far everything is good. Next, I want to find the values in listb that is greater than half of the maximum,

```
xss = []        # to get a list of 
for x in range(len(listb)):
    for a in range(len(listb[x])):
        if listb[x][a] > max(listb[x])/2.0:
            xss.append(a)
    
print(xss)
```

Now this works ok, but the problem that I have is that all the results from all 6 lines are appended in one list (xss), as such

```
[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92]
```

How can I make 6 different lists in my for loop?
Once I have that, I will be able to find min(xss) and max(xss) to find the difference, which corresponds to full-width half max of each line.

Here is the link to the csv file if you want to try:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Doxzr4I7-baQptbBBct-FFQOMsMmy9In/view?usp=sharing

Here is how plot looks like

[image: Here is how plot looks like]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, with a minimum change to your code:

```
xss = []
for x in range(len(listb)):
    xss_current = []
    for a in range(len(listb[x])):
        if listb[x][a] > max(listb[x])/2.0:
            xss_current.append(a)
    xss.append(xss_current)
```

Now xss contains the 6 lists.